# Is it possible to trigger a segue from a qr code reading in swift

Tags: ios, swift, camera, qr-code, scanning

I had a quick ios swift programing question. Is it possible to trigger a segue from a QR code reading in swift? I looked it up on Google and found this [app coda](http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-reader-swift/) tutroial. I still don't understand how I would go about doing it with a segue. could someone explain how they did it in there app? Thanks!

UPDATE

thanks Christian Woerz for the useful tip!

I found out how to do it!

when this function:

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

// Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
    qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRectZero
    messageLabel.text = "No QR code is detected"
    return
}

// Get the metadata object.
let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

if metadataObj.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode {
    // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
    let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(metadataObj as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject) as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
    qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject.bounds;

    if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
        messageLabel.text = metadataObj.stringValue
    }
  }
}
```

is fired do a `performSegueWithIdentifier(_ identifier: String?, sender sender: AnyObject?)` inside the function like this

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

// Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
    qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRectZero
    messageLabel.text = "No QR code is detected"
    return
}

// Get the metadata object.
let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

if metadataObj.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode {
    // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
    let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(metadataObj as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject) as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
    qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject.bounds;

    if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
        messageLabel.text = metadataObj.stringValue
    }
  }

**performSegueWithIdentifier(_ identifier: String?, sender sender:  AnyObject?)**

}
```

and pass in the Identifier of the segue like

> Identifier: thetransition

untested code but logic there :)

Comment: The short answer is yes; the longer answer is you can read QR codes in Swift and you can trigger segues programatically in Swift.  You need to write the code that will trigger the segue when you read a QR code - there is no magic "trigger a segue when you read a QR code function".

Comment: There is plenty of tutorials out there. If you have a specific code question just post your code and the error you might get. In the mean while you can read this [Building a QR Code Reader in Swift tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-reader-swift/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

But we can only give you a general answer, because there are many different ways and libraries to read a QR-code. But to give you a little example, you could use the QR code reader from [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-reader-swift/).
If you read a QR code with the code provided in this tutorial, a method will get called which receives the data of the QR code. In the tutorial it is `captureOutput`.

Then in this method you can add code to perform a segue if the method is called.